# First Difference transformation of log variable

Tags: econometrics, interpretation

I am using First difference transformation, where my variables are represented in a logarithmic form. How do I interpret the coefficients from such regressions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Same as always, the entire idea of first differing is to keep the interpretation but get rid of certain problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I just say that a 1% growth in X leads to a b% growth in Y, right?